# Iptables Hangs when listing rules

Tags: firewall, iptables

If I do iptables -L to list out all the rules in iptables, it will randomly hang at different ip addresses before continueing to print the list.  It hangs for a few seconds, and at different ip addresses each time.  My general rules are listed below.  then I have a couple local IPs and a few remote IPs that are allowed.  Is there a rule I forgot relating to lookups?

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `iptables` command will attempt a reverse lookup on ip addresses.  This will produce  exactly the behavior you describe.  You can inhibit the reverse lookup with the `-n` flag, which is why I always list rules like this:

```
iptables -vnL
```

This fact and many other useful tidbits can be found in the `iptables` man page.  The relevant section concerning `-n` reads:

```
-L, --list [chain]
List all rules in the selected chain. If no chain is selected, all chains
are listed. Like every other iptables command, it applies to the specified
table (filter is the default), so NAT rules get listed by

  iptables -t nat -n -L

Please note that it is often used with the -n option, in order to avoid
long reverse DNS lookups. It is legal to specify the -Z (zero) option as
well, in which case the chain(s) will be atomically listed and zeroed. The
exact output is affected by the other arguments given. The exact rules are
suppressed until you use

  iptables -L -v
```

Comment: That did the trick for the listing, Thanks.  Do you know if that reverse lookup happens when someone tries to connect, or machines are connecting to each other locally?  would there be a random delay if you do something like request a webpage from a webserver?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the actual kernel side doesn't care about DNS and won't do any reverse lookups.  This is just a "user friendly" feature of the user facing tools.

Comment: Would not have figured that out on my own for a very long time. Thank you.